# MYSQL: Where clause on cumulative sum not working when ORDER BY is added to query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying get all records from `storage_movements` table until the `weight` column sum reaches a specific value. This is the query that I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT id, storage_id, weight, (@total := weight + @total) as c_sum
FROM `storage_movements`
JOIN (SELECT @total := 0) r
WHERE @total < 100000
AND weight > 0
AND storage_id=4
AND id < 1000
ORDER BY id DESC
```

It does not works. It continues adding `@total` without respecting the `WHERE` clause (`@total` exceeds `100000` until all records are finished).

If I make some changes, strange things will happen. Like:

- If I remove `AND id < 1000` line, it works like expected (but I need this line).
- If I remove `ORDER BY id DESC` line, also works (but I also need this line).
- If I remove `AND storage_id=4`, it works (but I also need this line).
- If I change `AND storage_id=4` to `AND storage_id < 4`, it works (why, God?).

Can someone tell me why this happen, or show me how to do what I want?

Comment: JOIN (SELECT @total := 0) r should be a cross join

Comment: Using MySQL user variables within the same query level can be tricky because off the way user variables work.. i would place the initialisation and sorting within a delivered table and move the `WHERE @total < 100000` or `WHERE c_sum < 100000`  to the outer qeury.. Edit just little bit to late Gordan already posted a answer with what i said more or less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In more recent versions of MySQL you need to sort first:

```
SELECT id, storage_id, weight, (@total := weight + @total) as c_sum
FROM (SELECT sm.*
      FROM storage_movements sm
      WHERE weight > 0 AND storage_id = 4 AND id < 1000
      ORDER BY id
     ) sm CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @total := 0) r
WHERE @total < 100000;
```

I'm not thrilled with using `@total` in the `WHERE`.  I think I would go for:

```
SELECT id, storage_id, weight, (@total := weight + @total) as c_sum
FROM (SELECT sm.*
      FROM storage_movements sm
      WHERE weight > 0 AND storage_id = 4 AND id < 1000
      ORDER BY id
     ) sm CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @total := 0) r
HAVING c_sum < 100000;
```

Comment: Excellent! Works wonderful. Congratulations for your detailed answer. And thank you so much.